# Где нужно поставить запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: запятые

После прохождения первых двух этапов
регистрации Приложение просит ввести защитный
код который отображается на сгенерированном
в серверной части Приложения изображении.

Comment: А Вы как считаете?

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении нужна одна запятая: перед словом "который".